# EXC_BAD_ACCESS unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, exc-bad-access, unrecognized-selector

```
//adds a button to scroll list  
-(void) addNode:(NSString *) atitle{  
     UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];  
     [btn setTitle:atitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
     [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; // handle touch  
     [buttons addObject:btn];  
....
}

//a data button was pressed  
-(void) buttonTouched:(id)sender{  
   int index = [buttons indexOfObject:sender];  
   NSString *key = [sender titleLabel].text;  
}  

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate>

-(id) init{  
    self = [super init];  
    ...  
}  

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.  
- (void)viewDidLoad {  
 [super viewDidLoad];  
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ViewDidLoad" object:nil];  
}  

-(void) awakeFromNib{  
 [self loadData]; // loads some data  
  //calls addNode for a bunch of dynamic data
}
```

---

Getting this error:

```
2010-07-29 10:19:45.428 DataManager[2945:207] -[NSCFString buttonTouched:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x593abb0  
2010-07-29 10:19:45.429 DataManager[2945:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString buttonTouched:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x593abb0'  
*** Call stack at first throw:  
(  
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x02399919 __exceptionPreprocess + 185  
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x024e75de objc_exception_throw + 47  
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x0239b42b -[NSObject(NSObject)   doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187  
 3   CoreFoundation                      0x0230b116 ___forwarding___ + 966  
 4   CoreFoundation                      0x0230acd2 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50  
 5   UIKit                               0x002bde14 -[UIApplication  sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119  
 6   UIKit                               0x003476c8 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67  
 7   UIKit                               0x00349b4a -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527  
 8   UIKit                               0x003486f7 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458  
 9   UIKit                               0x00535070 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdateObserver + 3687  
 10  CoreFoundation                      0x0237ad1b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27  
 11  CoreFoundation                      0x0230f987 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295  
 12  CoreFoundation                      0x022d8c17 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575  
 13  CoreFoundation                      0x022d8280 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208  
 14  CoreFoundation                      0x022d81a1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97  
 15  GraphicsServices                    0x02bfe2c8 GSEventRunModal + 217  
 16  GraphicsServices                    0x02bfe38d GSEventRun + 115  
 17  UIKit                               0x002cbb58 UIApplicationMain + 1160  
 18  DataManager                         0x00002940 main + 102  
 19  DataManager                         0x000028d1 start + 53  
)  
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'  
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.  
kill  
kill  

The Debugger has exited due to signal 15 (SIGTERM).The Debugger has exited due to signal 15 (SIGTERM).
```

Answer (score 1):

I did add `[self retain];` before adding the action to the button and now it works!

```
-(void) addNode:(NSString *) atitle{  
UIButton *btn = [UIButton   buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];  
    [btn setTitle:atitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
    [self retain];  
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; // handle touch
```

Any reason why?
self is the `UIViewController` that handles everything (at least I thought)

Comment: Calling `[self retain];` opens the door for a big memory leak since you are bumping your view controller's `retainCount` up by 1 and never releasing the object again.  That has nothing to do with creating a button dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ARC compiles and programmatically setting the selector via:

```
[_backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

the EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs for me because I had created a parent and then added the subview to another view.  The subview (with the button) had its parent release.  Everything looked fine until the button was selected and then the crash.

Any exceptions with selectors are most probably class release issues. Retain should not be used as a work around (of course in ARC compiles you cannot use retain). Code should be review for possible widowed pointers in a function that will release the parent of the object.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is `buttons` an array that you initialized (I'm assuming since you are using `addObject` which is only for arrays)?  You say that it's supposed to add it to a scroll list (i'm guessing you meant a scrollview), but the error you are giving makes it seem like you are passing it into a string object.

To add to a scrollview, you would do:

```
[someScrollview addSubview:btn];
```

Also, I don't see anywhere that you set the frame of the object for when it gets added to the scrollview.  That's something you would need to do before adding it as a subview.

Works just fine for me (note, you should be initializing and releasing the mutable array somewhere, I just did this quickly):

Console output = 2010-07-29 15:54:54.563 Torch[52222:207] Yep Hi and 0

Code that I used:

```
NSMutableArray *buttons; // in your .h interface

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *buttons; // in your .h

@synthesize buttons; // in your .m
```

(...)

```
-(IBAction) pushMyButtons {  
buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];  
[btn setTitle:@"Hi" forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(65, 300, 200, 23)];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; // handle touch  
[buttons addObject:btn];
[self.view addSubview:btn];  
}

//a data button was pressed  
-(void) buttonTouched:(id)sender{  

int index = [buttons indexOfObject:sender];  
NSString *key = [sender titleLabel].text; 
NSLog(@"Yep %@ and %d", key, index);

}
```

Comment: My bad. Im newbie.   Yes buttons array initlized during init. Yes [scrollview addSubview:btn].   The problem is when i press the dynamically added button.

Comment: No prob, just trying to get as much info as possible :)  See my updated post, this works just fine for me.. Instead of adding it to a scrollview I just added it to a view real quick, but there is no difference in the two.  I made my button title "Hi"

Comment: Didnt work for some reason.  Thanks though.  See answer above.